# Xammp minimum version requirement to run Laravel 5.4 in Windows

Tags: xampp, version, laravel-5.4, minimum-requirements

- Need information about Xammp minimum version requirement to run Laravel 5.4 in Windows...!
- Explicitly, is XAMMP v3.2.2 can be used for running Laravel 5.4 in
  windows?

Comment: Just check PHP version included in XAMPP, should be >= 5.6.4

Comment: Thanks. I've got that info by going that directory (C:\xammp\php\) and check in command line " php -v"